# Javascript - Remove empty paragraphs from HTML string

Tags: javascript, html

In a Javascript object, I have a string of HTML (`node.innerHTML`) and I need to remove empty paragraphs from the string, then return the string.  Empty paragraphs include `<p></p>`, `<p> </p>`, and `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. Ideally, I think the string should be parsed as HTML code for processing as opposed to using a regex.  I have tried all sorts of approaches and cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Here is code I have tried, but it returns an object with only prevObject data, plus it does not seem to remove the empty paragraphs.

```
function strip_empty_p (node) {     
    var html = $(node.innerHTML);
    html = html.filter($('p'),function () {
        return this.innerHTML == "" ||
        this.innerHTML == " " ||
        this.innerHTML == "&nbsp;"
        }).remove();    
    node.innerHTML = html.innerHTML;
    return node.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: can we see your code

Comment: *" I have tried all sorts of approaches"* - Consider including them. This website isn't the place to request someone to write your code, but rather to help you fix your own. Without *giving* anything, you won't *get* anything. Please edit your question to show a sufficient attempt.

Comment: Loop through the children ,if the type = P, then only use innerHTML for parent

Comment: You can use jquery, get all paragraphs and return their innerHTML ou innerText depending on what do you want for it's content. E.g.: `$('p').each(function () { alert($(this).html()) })`

Comment: By not including what you've tried, guess what's going to happen?  We're going to suggest things that you've already tried, you'll reply saying "nope I tried that", and repeat.  That's a waste of everyone's time.  Including what you've tried lets us avoid that loop.  Now, since I value my time, it would be helpful to everyone if you could include your attempts and why they didn't work out for you.  (This is assuming you're on the level; plenty of people come here saying they tried all sorts of things, and its obvious they didn't bother trying at all.)

Comment: Sorry all, I did not include my current code in original question. I have updated the question with my current code. Other attempts included regex variations to remove empty paragraphs from the string but I don't think regex on on string is best approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a `node`, it'd be much better to run through it as HTML instead of getting `innerHTML` and parsing it that way.

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('div');

parent.childNodes.forEach(child => child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE 
  && !child.innerText.trim() 
  && parent.removeChild(child));
```

```html
<div>
 <p></p>
 <p> </p>
 <p>Not empty</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>Also not empty</p>
 <p></p>
</div>
```

This method will be infinitely more reliable and quicker than trying to parse it as if it were text.

If you load it as text from somewhere, convert it to an HTML node first, if it's well-formed enough.

If it's malformed HTML, then life becomes a lot more difficult and you'd have to do some tricky and error-prone string parsing.

Comment: `textContent` instead of `innerText` would also make this faster. `innerText` causes layout.

Comment: There are some differences to be aware of when choosing. In particular, using `textContent` will show hidden elements, which may or may not be desired given the intended use-case. A good note, and if you are okay with hidden elements being shown (or don't have any), then `textContent` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via jQuery. You can either check `.text()` or `innerHTML()` of the paragraphs. Here's an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akvap5mg/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text().trim() === '') {
            $this.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove empty paragraphs, one needs to exercise utmost caution if that is what you intend to literally do because every time an element gets removed it changes the whole ball game.  This is what ultimately worked for me:

```
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];


  for (i=0, max=4; i <= max; i++) {
     if ( d.children[i].textContent.trim() == ""){
                  d.removeChild(d.children[i]);
                    max--;
                    i--;
       }
  }
```

[live code](https://jsfiddle.net/mp0vq41p/85/)

If you don't adjust variables max and i, then detecting the DOM elements gets thrown off and an empty paragraph may not get removed.

Alternatively, the following code figuratively removes empty paragraphs and there is no need to adjust variables max and i:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];


  for (i=0, max=4; i <= max; i++) {
     if ( d.children[i].textContent.trim() == ""){
            d.children[i].style.display="None";
       }
  }
```

[live code](https://jsfiddle.net/mp0vq41p/87/)

Incidentally, here's a more vivid example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVWzmw)